# Deploy bigtable helloworld in flexible enviroment not works

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bigtable, app-engine-flexible

I am trying test the flexible environment with bigtable, it runs locally in jetty but when I upload to Google Cloud, appear a startup error.

I tried with this repo only adding a library in dependencies and I have error:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-servlet

This is the gradle:

```html
buildscript {      // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()      // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

repositories {   // repositories for JARs you access in your code
  maven {
    url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
  }

//maven {
//  url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT repository if needed
//}

  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

dependencies {
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
  providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
// Add your dependencies here.

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigtable/bigtable-hbase-1.2
  //compile group: 'com.google.cloud.bigtable', name: 'bigtable-hbase-1.2', version: '0.9.5.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client
  compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-client', version: '1.2.4'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static
  //compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-tcnative-boringssl-static', version: '1.1.33.Fork19'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl
  //compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'


}

// [START gretty]
gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'  // What App Engine Flexible uses
}
// [END gretty]

// [START model]
appengine {

  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
  }

}
// [END model]

group = 'com.example.appengine'   // Generated output GroupId
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'          // Version in generated output

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
// [END gradle]
```

I tried this other changed in app.yaml the variable vm:true to env:flex

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/gae-flexible-helloworld

The same error in all cases are:

```html
5e334b84d9b0: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:1ceadc6b20375e1b2548d533aba2382ae0adfbc8fca4ee619b25b08b39e2d8d7 size: 6966
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [bigtable2]...
.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
Archive:  /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root.war
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/META-INF/
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/com/
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/appengine/
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/appengine/gettingstartedjava/
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/appengine/gettingstartedjava/helloworld/
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/appengine/gettingstartedjava/helloworld/HelloServlet.class  
   creating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hbase-client-1.2.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hbase-annotations-1.2.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hbase-common-1.2.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hbase-protocol-1.2.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jcodings-1.0.8.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/joni-2.1.2.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.12.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-auth-2.5.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.5.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.2.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jettison-1.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/xz-1.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.5.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/guice-3.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar  
  inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/web.xml  
-XX:InitialHeapSize=514850816 -XX:MaxHeapSize=514850816 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC 
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-1~bpo8+1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

2017-03-31 19:25:38.517:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2121ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2017-03-31 19:25:39.614:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting umask=02
2017-03-31 19:25:39.661:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Opened ServerConnector@28d25987{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-03-31 19:25:39.670:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting GID=999
2017-03-31 19:25:39.673:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting UID=999
2017-03-31 19:25:39.679:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.1.v20170120
2017-03-31 19:25:39.708:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/] at interval 0

:appengineDeploy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appengineDeploy'.
> Non zero exit: 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appengineDeploy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:256)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:253)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:30)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.syncRun(DefaultProcessRunner.java:211)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.run(DefaultProcessRunner.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runGcloudCommand(CloudSdk.java:191)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runAppCommand(CloudSdk.java:120)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy(CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:88)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.task.DeployTask.deployAction(DeployTask.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: I've verified the problem and am fixing now.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/gae-flexible-helloworld) - it works with Maven  and Gradle now.

```
mvn clean appengine:deploy -Dbigtable.projectID=YOUR-PROJECT -D=bigtable.instanceID=YOUR-INSTANCE
```

or

```
gradle -Dbigtable.projectID=YOUR-PROJECT -D=bigtable.instanceID=YOUR-INSTANCE clean appengineDeploy
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with maven and gradle and not works, this is the error:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection
 at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:109)
 at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:95)
 at com.example.bigtable.BigtableHelper.connect(BigtableHelper.java:59)
 at ...

Comment: On GAE Standard J8 or Flex?  (I just fixed gradle for J8 Std).  On Flex, this will happen if you change versions of HBase in the pom.xml (or build.gradle).  You might wish to upgrade The bigtable artifact of 0.9.6.2 first.